# CREATE Rule insert in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables. I need the id value not to intersect between two tables (relative one to one). For example user => student and lecturer. the user cannot be both a teacher and a student. decided to implement it through the rule insert, but there is a problem with infinite recursion.

In the example I try to find new.IdPersonal in the lecturer table and if there is no it then to add new record to the student:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE "InsertId" AS ON INSERT TO "Student" 
    WHERE (NOT (NEW."IdPersonal" IN ( SELECT "Lecturer"."IdPersonal" FROM public."Lecturer")))
    DO INSERT INTO "Student"("Id", "IdPersonal", "IdGroup") 
    OVERRIDING SYSTEM VALUE VALUES (null, New."IdPersonal", New."IdGroup");
```

Comment: 1) Avoid rules at all costs, they will drive you crazy. 2) Use a trigger with trigger function instead.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for that is to use the same sequence to fill the `id` for both tables.